# Android Sending FCM Registration Token For Existing App User

Tags: java, android

My App is live and I have integrate push notification module using FCM for the first time in my App, Now I am getting the push message for new registered users, but not for the existing user.Can you please help me out so that the old/existing user can also get push notification message.

I am getting the FCM registered token by

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

and inserted into my database. But when it comes to the already logged in user, I can't figure it out how to generate the token for them(old logged in user)

Answer (score 0):

The fcm token is generated once for each user and changed in some cases like uninstalling the app or clear app data, so you have to store it in your data base once it has been generated and check if it has been changed to update it in your data base, you can track fcm token through `onTokenRefresh()` method and your code should be some thing like that

```
public class SendTokenIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    String TAG = "FireBase Token";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        //store in your data base
    }
}
```

Comment: I  did the same. I know that this token will trigger once when the app will install for the first time. I am done with that part. But for existing logged user, the token is not getting applicable which in turn they are not getting  the push notification.. Do you have any idea  regarding this.

Comment: those already existing users have your new version of the app with integrated fcm code ??

Comment: yes those already existing users will use my new version of the app with integrated fcm code